# Cannot read .arrow file in Google Cloud Run (using Python datasets.load_from_disk from HuggingFace)

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-run, pyarrow, huggingface-datasets

I am trying to build an Python app using GCP Cloud Run. The app is dockerized and I have no issue building and running the cointainer locally. However, when trying to build it via Google's Cloud Run, I get the following error :
`pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Expected to read 1936876918 metadata bytes, but only read 127`

The pyarrow library is called by the load_from_disk() function from the HuggingFace datasets package :

```
from datasets import load_from_disk

class TextEmbedder(ABC):
    def __init__(self, model_name, paragraphs_path, device, load_existing_index=False):
        self.dataset = load_from_disk(paragraphs_path)
    (...)

class SentenceTransformersTextEmbedder(TextEmbedder):
    (...)

text_embedder = SentenceTransformersTextEmbedder(...)
```

I have seen a similar issue here : https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues/398 that explains that it confusingly expects a file written not in the arrow file-format but in arrow stream-format but I don't see how to fix it in my case (neither why this error only occurs in the cloud) and I don't understand why there would be a difference between local container and in the cloud.

I am using Python 3.10, datasets 2.12.0
The arrow files have been created using datasets as well through the method save_to_disk(), but manually and beforehand, outside of the container.

```
from datasets import Dataset
(...)
paragraphs_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(paragraphs_dataframe)
paragraphs_dataset.save_to_disk(args.data_folder)
```

here is my dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.10
ARG GRADIO_SERVER_NAME="0.0.0.0"
ENV GRADIO_SERVER_NAME=${GRADIO_SERVER_NAME}
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["python", "-u", "./app.py"]
```

Does anyone understand why this happens and do you think there is a work around ?

Thank you,

I have been unsuccessfully looking for a way to 'force' the load_to_disk function to see the files as non-stream files or instead to create stream files instead when using save_to_disk. (to be honest I don't really understand the difference).
Alternatively, I suspect there might be a "storage_options" argument to pass to load_to_disk() that could help but no luck so far.

Comment: Can you also share how you build your container and where the arrow file is located?

Comment: Hello ! I have added the dockerfile in the original post. The arrow file is located in a data folder which is at the root of the project

Comment: How the library know it has to check in the /app directory to find the .arrow file. You can't pass some parameter for that?

Comment: I guess it is because it is setup as the working directory by `WORKDIR /app`. It is also a python default to set the root where the exexcuted script is located, which is in the /app directory. The access to the arrow file should not be the issue as the container works when run on my local computer.